# querySelector does not find Script Element

Tags: dart, dart-html

I have an HTML Element that looks like this:

```dart
<!--<div id="waves"></div>-->
<script type="WaveDrom" id="waves">
{signal: [
['input' , 
{name: 'a', wave: '01010101'},
{name: 'b', wave: '0.1.0.1.'},
{name: 'c', wave: '0...1...'}],
['output',
{name: 'expected d', wave: '01.010.1'},
{name: 'simulated d', wave: '01.010.1'},
{name: 'expected e', wave: '0..101..'},
{name: 'simulated e', wave: '0..101..'}]
]}
</script>
```

In Dart I now want to swap the contents of the ScriptElement with the id 'waves'. But the `querySelector('#waves')` does not return the ScriptElement (it returns null). If I add the DivElement it will find this just fine.

Is there something special about ScriptElements that they can't be queried like this? Or is this a bug in Dart?

Comment: Can you pleas add some code. Do you run the code directly in 'main'? Is your script tag in the had or the body?

Comment: The script is in the body.

Comment: Works as well when the script tag is in the body.

Comment: I copied your script tag and it works as well. I can print `x.innerHtml` to get the script content.

Comment: BTW: Selecting by id `'#waves'` works for me too.

Comment: I found the problem. The script is processed (and the id changed) before I can start execution with Dart. So my problem is another.. :)

Comment: I understand. You could use another property. `<script ... myid='waves'...>` with `querySelector('script[myid=waves]')`

Answer (score 2):

I have this in `main.dart`

```dart
void main() {
  var x = document.querySelector('script');
  print(x.attributes['src']);
}
```

and this in the HTML file

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class='target' id='target1'>ANIMATION 1</div>
    <div class='target' id='target2'>ANIMATION 2</div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

when I run it it prints

> packages/web_components/platform.js